# Как заставить nginx редиректить

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Хочу привести ссылки типа /catalog/xxx -> /catalog/xxx.html

пишу локейшн:

```
location /catalog/ {
    rewrite ^/catalog/(.*)$ /catalog/$1.html permanent;
}
```

Но в итоге при обращении к разделу site.ru/catalog/ попадаю на site.ru/catalog/.html

Comment: `location ~ ^/catalog/(.+)$ { return http://site.ru/catalog/$1.html; }` лучше так наверное. Перманент это `return 301 URL;`

Comment: Тоже не подходит, циклический редирект получается.

Comment: ну да, очевидно. `location ~ ^/catalog/(.+?)(?!\.html)$ { return http://site.ru/catalog/$1.html; }`. если до .html нет точек, то можно проще `location ~ ^/catalog/([^\.]+)$`

Comment: В данный момент все ссылки вида site.ru/catalog/bmw редиректятся на site.ru/catalog/bmw.html и это правильно, но если присутствует на конце url слеш site.ru/catalog/bmw/ то правило не срабатывает.

Comment: `^/catalog/(.+?)/?(?!\.html)$` или `^/catalog/([^\.]+?)/?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вы хотели? Раздел `site.ru/catalog/` под локейшн попадает? Попадает. Под регулярку попадает? Тоже попадает. Вот редирект и срабатывает.

Возможно, вам бы больше подошла регулярка `^/catalog/(.+)$`

Answer (score 0):

Проверил на регулярных выражениях, все правильно $1 - пустая строка.

Полагаю вам нужно правило: `^/catalog/([-A-Za-z0-9_’%]+)$` , которое не срабатывает на /catalog/ , но срабатывает на всем остальном, начинающемся с /catalog/ , например, на /catalog/xxx

Comment: Если использовать Вашу регулярку, то при заходе в /catalog/
http://site.ru/catalog/index.php.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html